# Eloquent - Laravel Can not using orderBy in eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I cannot get `orderBy` statement to work in eager loading function like Laravel docs

```
Book::with(['view' => function ($q)
{
     $q->orderBy('total', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

But when I using `join` statement it will be OK.

```
Book::join('views', 'views.book_id', '=', 'books.id')
->orderBy('total', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Is this just a TYPO, the one that works you have called `views` and the one that does not you have called `view`

Comment: `views` is the table name and `view` is method name.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work since it works that way so you first grab all the `Book` records and then fetch the `View` relations in another query. That's how eager loading works. So if you want to sort by some column from relation table you have to join it like you did in second snippet.